# Does the concept of damping apply to 1st order systems?

Tags: control, control-system, signal-processing, pid-controller

I'm just learning control systems. Today I learnt about 1st order and second order systems.

I understood Damping, Critically damped, over-damped and under-damped systems.

So a question arises in my mind "Does the concept of damping apply to 1st order and if so, whether all 1st order systems are over-damped or critically damped only?"

My thought is because 1st order systems don't have energy transfer element pairs such as capacitor and inductor like in 2nd order, so oscillations can never happen.

Is my thinking correct or am I missing some points here?

Comment: The term damping just doesn't apply to 1st order systems.

Comment: @Andyaka Yes, All the resources i read point to only second order systems. So i could not find anything related to 1st order regarding damping. Can you please elaborate why is it so.

Comment: There is nothing to elaborate - 1st order systems do not possess a parameter called damping.

Comment: First order systems only have one energy reservoir. Thus they cannot swing. That's why the *term* damping makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Damping means the *real part* of the *complex conjugate* pole is larger or smaller, relative to the magnitude of the pole. To be fair, it means much more, but mathematically that's where it gets to. A 1st order system has only real poles, for example:

$$H(s)=\frac{1}{s+1}\quad\Rightarrow\quad s=-1$$

There can be 2nd order systems, and higher, with real poles, and in those cases, damping no longer applies:

$$H(s)=\frac{1}{s^2+3s+2}=\frac{1}{(s+1)(s+2)}\quad\Rightarrow\quad s_1=-1\,,\,s_2=-2$$

But for a 2nd order system, or higher, where there are complex conjugate poles, the realpart is (considering a unity magnitude) \$\Re(s)=-\sqrt{1-\Im(s)^2}\$. With this you get [the usual pictures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping_ratio#Definition).

In short: you don't see the forest because of the trees, i.e. you got stuck in the namings and can't see the *meaning* of damping.

Answer (score 0):

> My thought is because 1st order systems don't have energy transfer
> element pairs such as capacitor and inductor like in 2nd order, so
> oscillations can never happen.

Correct. Damping is a measure of how fast oscillations die out. For a typical plot of an underdamped system you can see a sine wave start then die away. An overdamped system is sufficiently heavily damped that you can only see the initial part of a sine wave.

A first order system can't oscillate, as you note. There's nothing to damp so the concept of damping doesn't apply. Instead, we have the concept of a time constant to characterise a first order system.